# Capture MySQL query result as var [js]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm currently trying to build a discord bot, and I want to use a database for some aspects of it. Currently, I'm trying to add a command that would return the names of all the tables I have in the database, and for the most part I have it down.

The part that I'm struggling with is actually getting the names back out as a var. Every guide and stackoverflow question that I've been able to find on it assume that you just want to get that result and then print it to the console, but I need to return it back to the method that called this.

My previous attempt was setting an outside variable and using a promise to wait for it to change, but I couldn't get that to work, most likely because I don't fully understand how Promises work. My current attempt uses `setTimeout()` to check, but that just returns the asyncID of either the first or second iteration.

Any help either in making either of these work or completely scrapping them and doing this a different way is very welcome.

Previous code:

```js
function listTables() {
    db.query('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=\'' + dbName + '\'', (error, results) => {
        if(error) throw error;
        let temp = '';
        results.forEach((item) => {
            temp += item.table_name + ', ';
        }); temp = temp.slice(0, -2);
        setReturn(temp);
    });
    
    let out = checkReturn().then((value) => {
        return value();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return '';
    });
    returnValue = null;
    return out;
}



var returnValue = null;
function setReturn(value) {
    returnValue = value;
}
async function checkReturn() {
    console.log('Checking Return: ' + returnValue);
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(returnValue === null) reject('Var not set');
        else resolve(returnValue)
    });
    return await promise;
}
```

Current Code:

```js
function listTables() {
    setReturn(null);
    db.query('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=\'' + dbName + '\'', (error, results) => {
        if(error) throw error;
        let temp = '';
        results.forEach((item) => {
            temp += item.table_name + ', ';
        }); temp = temp.slice(0, -2);
        setReturn(temp);
    });
    return checkReturn();
}



var returnValue = null;
function setReturn(value) {
    returnValue = value;
}
function checkReturn() {
    console.log('Checking Return: ' + returnValue);
    if(returnValue === null) {
        return setTimeout(checkReturn, 50);
    } else {
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `listTables` function to return a promise.

```
function listTables() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=\'' + dbName + '\'', (error, results) => {
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            let temp = '';
            results.forEach((item) => {
                temp += item.table_name + ', ';
            }); temp = temp.slice(0, -2);
            resolve(temp);
        });
    });
}

// Usage of `listTables()`
listTables()
    .then(result -> {
        // Do process result
    });
```

Comment: And that was exactly what I needed for promises to click. Thank you much, it works perfectly!